# how to display list on datgridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
List A = new List();
A.Add("Apple");
A.Add("Banana");
A.Add("Pineapple");

dataGridView.DataSource = a;
```

Result: is the length of each item in the list rather than Item itself.
5
6
9
How can I make datagridView to display string instead of length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a class, Fruit

```
class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and create a generic list of fruits:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();
fruits.Add(new Fruit() { Name = "Apple" });

dataGridView1.DataSource = fruits;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also do some funky LINQ

```
List<string> A = new List<string>(); A.Add("Apple"); A.Add("Banana"); A.Add("Pineapple");
dataGridView.DataSource = (from a in A select new {Value = a}).ToList();
```

edit

To explain a bit further, the issue is that the datagridview is binding to the default property of the object (so a string is length) there is no real property in a string (like value for instance) for you to set DataMember too so you have to create a class, or in my case give it an anonymous class with just one property (or many properties and set DataMember)

Comment: this is second time. I sure I will never forget this.thank a lot for brief explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `DataGridView` looks for properties of containing objects. For string there is just one property - length. So, you need a wrapper for a string like this

```
public class StringValue 
{ 
  public StringValue(string s) 
  { 
      Value = s; 
  } 
  public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } } 
  string _value; 
}
```

Then bind `List<StringValue> object` to your grid. Just an alternate answer

edit: unintentional complete copy of someone elses answer in a different topic, seems the person who taught me this just copied the answer from there, and a few years later, ive brought it back, unintentional and apologies